# Clip and spatial join of hydrology polygon layer with district layer using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, clip, spatial-join, arcgis-10.4

I have two shapefiles I am attempting to join spatially. One is a county polygon file and the other is a hydrology polygon layer spread throughout various districts within it.

I'd like to output a shapefile and attribute table that breaks the hydrology file by district so pieces of the hydrology file are separated and can be associated with respective borders that they fall within.

What are the steps to achieve this?

I am running ArcGIS desktop 10.4. Right now I'm trying to clip the hydrology layer from the district layer. Spatial join just doesn't break the hydrology file.it gives most of the hydrology parcels to one district and although I can see which districts it covers in a list the polygon itself is unchanged. So I couldn't show which part of the lake is contained within a particular district. I'm trying to select a district, clip the hydrology file based on that one district then output a shapefile. I'll do this for all. Trying to do it with python.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?  What have you tried?

Comment: I am running arcgis desktop 10.4. Right now I'm trying to clip the hydrology layer from the district layer. Spatial join just doesn't break the hydrology file.it gives most of the hydrology parcels to one district and although I can see which districts it covers in a list the polygon itself is unchanged. So I couldn't show which part of the lake is contained within a particular district. I'm trying to select a district, clip the hydrology file based on that one district then output a shape file. I'll do this for all. Trying to do it with python.

Comment: I would try a Union, then Split Vector Layer.

Comment: I've tried the union but that hasn't been successful. The union breaks are messy and you can't properly distinguish which polygons are the district and which are the hydrology polygons.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways- Here are the general options. Not clear if you are writing a script or using the desktop tool.

1) Spatial join -A means to add or "Join" attribute table of one feature to the target feature based on spatial location- In this case, joining the hydrology file to the county file.  This creates a new output file.

or-

2) use the "union" option to overlay the hydrology file with the county file. This creates a new layer.

After choosing one of the above, you are able to "Select Layer by Attribute". The attribute would be the district. The hydrology features within the "selected" district will be highlighted in the attribute table. You can output the selection to an output file.

Comment: Like I said in the prior comment the union doesn't neatly break the two layers. Some work but many are unrecognizable and can't be distinguished as district or hydrology

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS, you may use the "Clip" tool from Processing (Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Clip).

I don't understand if your hydrology layer is a Linestring or a Polygon layer, however this should work in both cases. If you start from something like this:

[image]

you only need to click on the "Iterate over this layer" button in the options for the clip layer (see image below):

[image]

The tool will iterate over each feature of the clip layer, clipping the features from the input layer which are within it. This will be the result:

[image]

Every output layer will mantain the attributes from the input layer (in this case, the hydrology layer): if you need the attributes from the clip layer, you may simply join them with a further step.

Please note that the number of output layers will be equal to the number of features from the clip layer, so you may obtain some empty output layers for that cases where there is not any feature within the clip layer.